# composite.xml of project is generating warnings in jdeveloper 12c

Tags: xml, jdeveloper, oracle12c

I developed a `SOA` project in `JDeveloper 12c`in which I am just producing a message in a JMS queue through JMS Adapter. Now the composite.xml of the project is not able to find the endpoint client of the BPEL Process. Also, it is giving warning that there is incorrect namespace definition for the jca of JMS adapter.

Please tell me how to resolve this. Attached are the screenshots.

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6vMD.png)

[Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsByI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Incorrect namespace definition for the jca for the JMS adapter can be fixed by making it:

"../Adapters/jmsReference_jms.jca"

It seems its just not able to find the file in the path. I broke my head for a couple of hours before I could figure this out.

Comment: By changing it as specified, the warning has been removed but now it is giving me a compilation error that it could not find the jca file. Could this be a bug of JDeveloper 12c?